# I get 'fatal error C1083' when trying to install a node.js package, even when I have the VS build tools installed on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015, npm, discord

This is the command I'm running:

```
npm install -g install discord-irc
```

This is what my error log looks like:

> C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\discord-irc ->
>   C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\discord-irc\dist\index.js
>
> > node-icu-charset-detector@0.2.0 install C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\discord-irc\node_modules\node-icu-charset-detector
> >     node-gyp rebuild
>
> C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\discord-irc\node_modules\node-icu-charset-detector>if
>   not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )  Building the projects in this
>   solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m"
>   switch.   node-icu-charset-detector.cpp   win_delay_load_hook.cc
>   ..\node-icu-charset-detector.cpp(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open
>   include file: 'unicode/ucsdet.h': No such file or directory
>   [C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\discord-irc\node_modules\node-icu-charset-detector\build\node-icu-charset-detector.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm `-- discord-irc@2.1.7    +--
>   UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY erlpack@hammerandchisel/erlpack#master   +--
>   UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY node-opus@^0.2.0   +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY
>   opusscript@^0.0.1`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY uws@^0.12.0

Here's my installer that shows the build tools:

[image]

I suspect it has something to do with the install location. So I made sure the build tools are in the PATH variable.

[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?